# How to build CEFSharp (CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll) from source code

Tags: c#, nuget, cefsharp

I downloaded the cefsharp project through NuGet, which contains a dll file `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll`. I downloaded the source code of the cefsharp project and modified some of the code because of business needs.

I use vs2015. But I found that the generated `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll` file is twice as large as before, but I have not modified its source code. How can I generate a DLL like NUGET?

Comment: You must build in `Release` mode. The project uses a powershell script to compile and generate the packages. It's called `build.ps1` and is in the project root.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Building-Nupkg-Files

Comment: Thank you.I downloaded the package from Visual Studio's NUGET in the directory (D:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WB\packages\CefSharp.Common.67.0.0) and I saw that there is a SRC directory. What methods or tools can I use to build them?

Comment: You cannot build that source, it's purely there for reference purpose. The project source is on `GitHub`.